# Can you cause Qt to assert, segfault, or otherwise crash when a QObject::connect() fails?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm using Qt 4.8.x so I don't have access to the new `connect` interface from Qt5, but I want to be alerted better when a signal/slot connection fails because I misspelled a signal or slot name.

Currently, all Qt does is spit out an error message when the connection is attempted. However, my program has a lot of output on `stdout` so it is easy to miss these errors sometimes. Is it possible to force my application to crash via assert, segfault, or other method, when a connect statement fails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes: set the `QT_FATAL_WARNINGS` environment variable to a non-zero value.

You can do this during development in Qt Creator by going to the Projects pane, click Run, then under "Run Environment" click Details, then click Add.

*Edit to add*: you can of course also implement some wrappers for QObject::connect, that will check its return value and assert() if it returns false.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to do this?

Comment: I'll be more specific in my question. Is this an OS environment variable? Or is it something that you set in the `.pro` file? How do you set the `QT_FATAL_WARNINGS` environment variable to a non-zero value?

Comment: It's an OS environment variable; how to set it depends on your OS/IDE. When using Creator, you can set additional environment variables in the Project pane, under the Run settings. Under Linux/Unix with a `sh`-like shell, you can run `QT_FATAL_WARNINGS=1 ./YourApp` or `setenv QT_FATAL_WARNINGS=1` to set it permanently in that shell. Under Windows it's somewhere in the Control Panel -> System.

Comment: This worked for me - add this line `qputenv("QT_FATAL_WARNINGS","1");` near the beginning of your `main()` function.

Answer (score 4):

I think at least one of the solutions in this question: [Qt GUI app: warning if QObject::connect() failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486545/qt-gui-app-warning-if-qobjectconnect-failed) does what you need.

In particular, by using `QErrorMessage::qtHandler` you should be able to intercept those warnings and do whatever you want with them.